# AngularJS with twig

Tags: php, angularjs, twig, symfony

i'm confused about situation. I'm using angular js with twig. Try to transfer variable to function. Variable value is the index.
**When i click on element i get the name of variable instead of value.**

**View looks like this**

```
<ul ng-controller="Repeatable" class="tags-list" ng-init="init('{{ form.tags.vars.value|json_encode() }}')">
    {% verbatim %}
    <li class="tag" ng-repeat="entity in entities">
        <input type="text" name="article[tags][{{$index}}][name]" class="form-control"
               value="{{entity}}"/>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Delete" ng-click="remove('{{$index}}')">
            X
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endverbatim %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-article btn-main" ng-click="add()">
        {{ 'article.add_tag'|trans }}
    </button>
</ul>
```

**Html**
[image]

**Console log**
[image]

**UPDATE**

No problems. I tried without verbatim. Now view looks like this. Cache cleared.

```
<ul ng-controller="Repeatable" class="tags-list" ng-init="init('{{ form.tags.vars.value|json_encode() }}')">
    <li class="tag" ng-repeat="entity in entities">
        <input type="text" name="article[tags][{{ '{{$index}}'}}][name]" class="form-control"
               value="{{ '{{entity}}' }}"/>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Delete" ng-click="remove('{{'{{$index}}'}}')">
            X
        </a>
    </li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-article btn-main" ng-click="add()">
        {{ 'article.add_tag'|trans }}
    </button>
</ul>
```

In function i get **{{$index}}**, in html i see valid value...

Comment: You're passing a string to your `remove()` function, i.e. `'1'`, instead of `1`. Is that intentional? What happens if you remove the quotes?

Comment: Then i got parse error. Value must be in quates.